# Grab value based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

this is my table:

```
    idMission Event               Timestamp
    1         detectedBubbleOut 2018-05-26T12:53:43.000Z
    1         arrived               2018-05-26T13:58:57.000Z
    1         detectedInBuilding    2018-05-26T12:42:20.000Z
    1         detectedBubbleIn  2018-05-26T12:37:36.000Z
    1         detectedTimeOut       2018-05-26T12:52:17.000Z
    1         scanFulfilled     2018-05-26T12:41:26.000Z
    1         detectedBubbleIn  2018-05-26T12:37:22.000Z
    1         customerInteraction   2018-05-26T13:59:04.000Z
    1         scanFulfilled     2018-05-26T13:59:01.000Z
    1         delFulfilled      2018-05-26T12:48:30.000Z
    1         eventFulfilled        2018-05-26T12:48:30.000Z
    1         nextDelivery      2018-05-26T12:50:20.000Z
    1         customerInteraction   2018-05-26T12:48:18.000Z
    1         detectedOutBuilding   2018-05-26T12:49:21.000Z
    1         arrived               2018-05-26T12:40:09.000Z
    1         detectedTimeIn        2018-05-26T12:38:58.000Z
    2         nextDelivery          2018-05-27T12:50:20.000Z
    2         customerInteraction   2018-05-27T12:48:18.000Z
    2         detectedOutBuilding   2018-05-27T12:49:21.000Z
    2         arrived               2018-05-27T12:40:09.000Z
    2         detectedTimeIn        2018-05-27T12:38:58.000Z
```

There are some events associated with a timestamp, this is when the event happens. I'm focusing on the events "arrived" and "detectedTimeIn", but the event "detectedTimeIn" is not always available so i use "arrived". 
All i want is to grab the timestamp  based on specific event.
If  the event "detectedTimeIn" exists then i grab its timestamp, if it does not exists then i'll grab the timestamp of the event "arrived".
This is what i've achieved so far:

```
    select 
        event,
        stp."timestamp" as TimeIN
    from main_source_execevent_coop stp
    where event Coalesce('detectedTimeIn', 'arrived')
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
1         detectedTimeIn        2018-05-26T12:38:58.000Z
2         arrived               2018-05-27T12:40:09.000Z
```

But it's not working i obtain only:
1         detectedTimeIn        2018-05-26T12:38:58.000Z

Ignoring the "arrived" row.
Have you any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show your expected results.

Comment: is not it so, that you coalesce grabs its first argument as a result all the time ?

Comment: The question is not clear. did you have any primary key to this result set?

Comment: I've updated the question with the result i expect vs the result i obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at the "next" or "previous" event, use `lead()`/`lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select stp.*,
             lag(event) over (order by timestamp) as prev_event
      from main_source_execevent_coop stp
     ) stp
where event = 'detectedTimeIn' or
      (event = 'arrived' and next_event is distinct from 'detectedTimeIn');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT event,
    stp."timestamp" as TimeIN
FROM your_table
      WHERE event ='detectedTimeIn'
      LIMIT 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT event,
    stp."timestamp" as TimeIN
FROM your_table
      WHERE event ='arrived'
      LIMIT 1) a
LIMIT 1
```